# Unknown property 'actionSupportController.eachRecord'

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I am getting this above mentioned error. Please help me.

**Controller:**

```
 public class actionSupportController {
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}          
    public string test{get;set;} 


    public Void incrementCounter() {
       string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test' ;
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);

    }

     public Void doSearch(){
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }    
}
```

**Visualforce:**

```
    <apex:page controller="actionSupportController">
    <apex:form >        
                Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" rerender="pblck,msg"/>

       <apex:pageBlock id="pblck" >
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstQuery}" var="eachRecord" >

            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Household__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord['Name']}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Phone__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Childrens__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Address__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Previous_Dog__c}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
       </apex:pageBlock>

             <!--<apex:outputpanel id="panel1" >
                    <apex:outputText value="Click here to increment!"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!incrementCounter}" rerender="out"/>                   
                </apex:outputpanel>

                 <apex:outputpanel id="panel2">
                    <apex:outputText value="Click here to decrement!"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!decrementCounter}" rerender="out"/>
                </apex:outputpanel>-->

                <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.ID}" id="out" label="Count Is:"/>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What do you expect from this expression in your pageblocktable `{!eachRecord['Name']}` ?

Comment: {!eachRecord['Name']} standard field . so assigned like this.

Comment: Just try adding `{!eachRecord.Name}`

Comment: yes i did again i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"eachRecord" is your pageBlockTable iteration variable. This will not be accessible after your PageBlockTable.

Remove or modify the following line -

```
    <apex:outputText value="{!eachRecord.ID}" id="out" label="Count Is:"/>
```

You can use a different variable to count the list size